# kubernetes cronjob only runs once?

Tags: kubernetes

I created a k8s CronJob with the following schedule (run every minute):

`schedule: "*/1 * * * *"`

I see my CronJob created:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
job-staging   job-1593017820-tt2sn   2/3     Running   0          10m
```

My job simply does a Printf to the log, one time, then exits.

When I do a `kubernetes get cronjob` I see:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
job-staging   job   */1 * * * *      False   1         19m        19m
```

When I look at the logs, it looks like it only ran once, which was the first run. Do I need to prevent my program from exiting?

I assumed k8s would restart my program, but maybe that's a wrong assumption.

Comment: Script is this

`func main() {
 log.Printf("job: start")
 log.Printf("job: done")
}
`

Comment: `apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.CronJob }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.CronJob }}-{{ .Values.ServiceStage }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.CronJob }}-{{ .Values.ServiceStage }}
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 20
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 20
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          name: scheduler-cron
        spec:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption about the behavior of Kubernetes ("restarting the program") is correct.

As you may know, a Job is basically a Kubernetes Pod that executes some process and successfully finishes when it *exits with a zero exit code*. The "Cron" part of CronJob is the most obvious, scheduling the Job to execute in a particular time pattern.

Most YAML objects for CronJobs include the `restartPolicy: OnFailure` key that prevents Kubernetes from rescheduling the Job for a **non-zero exit code** (the [hello-world YAML file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#example) in Kubernetes documentation uses this flag).

From what I see in the logs obtained by your `kubectl` instruction, it looks like your Job is failing - because of the `Status 1`. I would recommend you check the logs of the CronJob using `kubectl logs -f -n default job-1593017820-tt2sn` for any possible errors in the execution of your script (if your script explicitly exits with an exit-code, check for a possible non-zero code).

[UPDATE]

CronJobs also have limitations:

> A cron job creates a job object about once per execution time of its schedule. We say “about” because there are certain circumstances where two jobs might be created, or no job might be created. We attempt to make these rare, but do not completely prevent them. Therefore, jobs should be idempotent.

I think these are pretty rare scenarios, but maybe you've found yourself in these rare situations. The documentation is [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#cron-job-limitations).

Comment: I do have `restartPolicy: OnFailure`. My script executes with no problem. Even adding `os.Exit(0)` as the last line in my script doesn't make a difference, the job still doesn't restart.

Comment: I have other containers running in the pod. They may be keeping the pod around, causing it to not terminate, and thus not reschedule the next job.

Comment: If there are no issues with the script, the image is up-to-date for consumption and the YAML definition is on-point I would say that you could probably be reaching a limitation for the CronJob. I will update my answer to reflect these limitations.

Comment: Now that you've mentioned it, from your spec the flag `concurrencyPolicy: Forbid` and your suspicion on the Pod not terminating, the CronJob controller would not reschedule the Job while the last one haven't finished. To verify this, change the flag to "Allow", submit the CronJob and run `kubect get jobs --watch`, you will probably see multiple jobs being spawned (one each minute) with status `Running` without terminating. Then you can try reading the logs from the pod or from kubernetes (with `kubectl describe job/{name}`) to learn more about the reason.

Comment: Yeah, the other two containers in my pod never terminate (they are sidecars needed to call other services). I need to figure out a way to terminate them when the job completes.

Comment: This [thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25908) can help you, from what I've seen (I've never had this use case) people usually communicate state changes using files (stored in volumes). When communicating with sidecars I like using ZeroMQ consumer patterns between my containers. I hope I could help you out! Cheers!